# Capifony ssh via different port

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, production, capifony

Is there any way to configure the SSH port in capifony deploy.rb file? By default the port is set to 22, but my server runs SSH on different one. 
How to change it?

The error I'm getting is connection failed for: [IP](Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "[IP]" port 22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search for "capifony ssh port" gave the [docs](http://capifony.org/reference/capistrano.html) as the first result which has...

```
If you connect to your production server using a non-traditional port,
set the port manually:

    ssh_options[:port] = "22123"
```

Comment: Thank you. Just couldn't find it.